# Linked list in C; delete() and search()

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm newbie in C and this is my first code regarding linked list, I have been working on this code for 3 days and ain't finished yet ,the program is about taking data from the user about employees  and edit or delete or search by id.

I am facing problem in the main function in the switch case; case 1,2,3.

case1 : i need the program to stop taking the same data (duplication ), the code can take the same name and id many times

case2 , case 3: when i run this code it's stop working

and i'm using code-blocks10.05 for win7 with gcc compiler

```
     #include <stdio.h>  
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include<malloc.h>

typedef struct emp

{  
    int id;
    char nm;
    struct emp *prev;
    struct emp *next;
}list;
  list *start;
  list *end;

///////////////////////////////////// Functios /////////////////////////////////////

void initlist (void);
struct emp *create_emp(void);    
void append_emp( struct emp *element);    
int  delete_emp(int d);    
void edit_emp(int old , int current);    
list *display ();    
struct emp *search_emp(int s);  

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////// MAIN ////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{   
int cases;
char nm1;int id1;list *c1; list *i1;    
int c2,del;
int old3,new3;
int i5;list *c5;


initlist();

    printf("\nLinked List for Employees\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Press 1 to INSERT an Employee into the list \n");

    printf("Press 2 to DELETE an Employee from the list \n");
    printf("Press 3 to EDIT Employee \n");
    printf("Press 4 to DISPLAY the list \n");    
    printf("Press 5 to SEARCH the list \n");    
    printf("Press 6 to EXIT the program\n");    
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");

    while (1)
        {
            scanf("%d",&cases);
           if (cases ==6)
            {
                break;
            }

           switch(cases) 
           { 
               case 1: //why when i run this code it's stop working   
                           c1=create_emp();
                           append_emp(c1);    
                           printf("Enter the new name : ");    
                           scanf("%c\n",& nm1);    
                           printf("Enter the new id : ");    
                           scanf("%d\n",& id1);    
            // what code i can write here to stop enter the same data to diff. emp.
                           i1 ->id =id1;
                           c1->nm=nm1;
                break;


                case 2: //why when i run this code it's stop working

        printf("Enter the Employee id you want to delete\n");

                            scanf("%d\n",c2);    
                            del=delete_emp(c2);    
                            if (del == 0)    
                            {    
                                printf("Not found");
                            }    
                            else    
                            {    
                                printf("Removed form list");
                            }   
                break;


                case 3: //why when i run this code it's stop working

                            printf("Enter the Employee id you want to Edit \n");
                            scanf("%d",old3);    
                            printf("Enter the new Employee id");    
                            scanf("%d",new3);    
                            edit_emp(old3,new3);    
                break;       

                case 4:
                            display();    
                break;   

                case 5:    
                            printf("Enter the id you'r searching for :");    
                            scanf("%d",i5);    
                            c5=search_emp(i5);    
                            if(c5==NULL)    
                            printf("not found\n");    
                            else    
                            printf("found\n");        
                break;  

           }
        }
   }

///////////////////////////////////// Creat list ///////////////////////////

void initlist (void)
{
    start=end=NULL;
}



    ///////////////////////////////////// Create emp /////////////////////////////////////
struct emp *create_emp(void)
{
    return ((struct emp*)malloc(sizeof(struct emp)));
}

///////////////////////////////////// Insert emp /////////////////////////////////////
void append_emp( struct emp *element )
{
    if ((start==NULL)&&(end==NULL))
    {
        start=element;
        end=element;
        element->next=NULL;
        element->prev=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        end->next=element;
        element->prev=end;
        end=element;
        element->next=NULL;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////// Delete emp /////////////////////////////////////
int  delete_emp(int d)
{
    struct emp *temp;
    temp=search_emp (d);
    if(temp==NULL)
    return 0;
    if(start==end)
    {
        start=NULL;
        end=NULL;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
    else if(temp==start)
    {
        start=start->next;
        start->prev=NULL;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
    else if (temp==end)
    {
        end=temp->prev;
        end->next=NULL;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->prev->next=temp->next;
        temp->next->prev=temp->prev;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////// Edit emp /////////////////////////////////////
void edit_emp(int old , int current)
{
    list * temp;
    temp = search_emp(old);
    if (temp==NULL)
    {
        printf("NOT EXIST\n");
    }
    else
    {
        temp->id =current;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////// Display list /////////////////////////////////////
list *display ()
{
    int d=1;
    list*temp;
    temp=start;
    while (temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("The Employee %d ID is : %d\n",d,temp->id);
        temp=temp->next;
        d++;
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////// Search dy ID /////////////////////////////////////
struct emp *search_emp(int s)
{
    struct emp *temp;
    temp=start;
    while((temp!=NULL)&&(temp->id!=s))
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: For your code, this is the right place http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if you want to tell us exactly what you want the code to do, what it currently does that's not what you want, then we can help you.  We won't write your code for you, though.  We get paid to do that.

Comment: I took a look at your code a little bit, there are too many mistakes. It would take too long to point what are wrong. It would be better for you to restudy the functions that you are using. minimize the errors then ask your specific question.

Comment: @eng - first make sure your compiler does not give any warnings when you compile.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what compiler you are using but in MSVC
`/Wall` gives this after a compile

http://xdcclan.com/images/warning.jpg